# Competitions: Storing an arbitrary number of fields

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, database-design

I'm going to be creating competitions on the current site I'm working on. Each competition is not going to be the same and may have a varying number of input fields that a user must enter to be part of the competition eg.

Competition 1 might just require a firstname

Competition 2 might require a firstname, lastname and email address.

I will also be building a tool to observe these entries so that I can look at each individual entry.

My question is what is the best way to store an arbitrary number of fields? I was thinking of two options, one being to write each entry to a CSV file containing all the entries of the competition, the other being to have a db table with a varchar field in the database that just stores an entire entry as text. Both of these methods seem messy, is there any common practice for this sort of task?

I could in theory create a db table with a column for every possible field, but it won't work when the competition has specific requirements such as "Tell us in 100 words why..." or "Enter your 5 favourite things that.."

**ANSWERED:**

I have decided to use the method described below where there are multiple generic columns that can be utilized for different purposes per competition.

Initially I was going to use EAV, and I still think it might be slightly more appropriate for this specific scenario. But it is generally recommended against because of it's poor scalability and complicated querying, and I wouldn't want to get into a habit of using it. Both answers worked absolutely fine in my tests.

Comment: if you are looking for memory entity to store arbitrary number of fields i think `List` should be best.

Comment: Thanks, not so much looking for storing in memory however. I'm looking where to store a solid copy that may sit there for a month at a time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are right to be cautious about EAV as it will make your code a bit more complex, and it will be a bit more difficult to do ad-hoc queries against the table.

I've seen many enterprise apps simply adopt something like the following schema -

```
t_Comp_Data
-----------    
CompId  
Name  
Surname  
Email 
Field1 
Field2 
Field3 
... 
Fieldn
```

In this instance, the generic fields (Field1 etc) mean different things for the different competitions. For ease of querying, you might create a different view for each competition, with the proper field names aliased in.

Comment: That's an interesting idea but it doesn't take into account the arbitrary length, not that I'm expecting a competition to have 200 different fields. But a single field over in this case means I'll have to change the database design. Decisions, decisions...

Comment: Usually, I've seen people just select a good sized number  - perhaps 50 fields. You only use the required fields for each particular competition. So if a comp only requires 2 generic fields, you will only fill out Field1 and Field2. 

Yes, it's a bit clunky and slightly wasteful, but I suspect you will find EAV to be more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: I'm also in favour of being able to extract the purpose of a piece of data from the database, so there doesn't need to be an extra step of looking up what, say, Field4 is in a particular competition.  Maybe a less strict database like SQLite is worth looking at.  I believe it doesn't enforce table schema on rows.

Comment: I am going to have to have a closer look at my options here. Both ways seem suitable but are not without their problems. I will update later tonight with the method I've chosen.

Answer (score 1):

I'm usually hesitant to use it, but this looks like a good situation for the Entity-attribute-value model if you use a database.

Basically, you have a CompetitionEntry (entity) table with the standard fields which make up every entry (Competition_id, maybe dates, etc), and then a CompetitionEntryAttribute table with CompetitionEntry_id, Attribute and Value.You probably also want another table with template attributes for each competition for creating new entries.

Unfortunately you will only be able to store one datatype, which will likely have to be a large nvarchar.
Another disadvantage is the difficulty to query against EAV databases.

Another option is to create one table per competition (possibly in code as part of the competition creation), but depending on the number of competitions this may be impractcal.

Comment: Reading around on EAV, it seems to have a bit of opposition, which seems mostly due to the query difficulty and speed it takes to get a useful report. It seems like a pretty good choice in my opinion though considering the amount of querying on the data would be fairly minimal. Would it be a bad to have an optional field on the CompetitionEntryAttribute table called "csharp_type" or something so that if need be I could configure certain fields for calculations? Again, that sounds quite messy to me...

Comment: I actually quite like the idea of storing the original type in the database, but I would probably store it next to the attribute template row, assuming a foreign key from each value row back to the template row.

Comment: Ah right the template table, that would be a much better place for it. I think I'll go with this EAV layout because the scaling issue is highly unlikely to affect me and if it does I'll probably be hitting plenty of other bottlenecks anyway! Thanks.